# unable to connect database : Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have noticed some unexpected behavior while connecting MySQL Codeigniter

Here is scenario:

-> I configured database library for autoload. (config/autoload.php)

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

-> But after configuring that, I can't open anything. I mean to say, Controller or View.

Have I done something wrong?

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'myfamilyfirst';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I tried to set `$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;` to `$db['default']['autoinit'] = FALSE;`

Now I can open the pages but unable to connect the database.

Please help.

Comment: can you connect to your database in other ways?

Comment: If your are using codeigniter 3.0 or newer, the `mysql` driver as been deprecated. You should use `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: @Abdulla, there is a blank window only...

Comment: @dgig yes.. I can connect via php script.

Comment: @Adrian  can you help me connection via pdo?

Comment: @TusharNiras You just need to add `$db['default']['dsn'] = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=myfamilyfirst; charset=utf8;'` and change the driver to `pdo`

Comment: Please add this into application/config/config.php and check error message >> error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are using new `xampp` or `wamp`. So it will not support `mysql`.

Change this

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; # Change
```

Comment: I tried : not working for me. Screen blank whenever I user active records blank page appears.

Comment: PHP Version : 5.6.4 and MySQL : 5.6.27

Comment: what is you localhost server ??

Comment: I'm using apache2 as web server

Comment: One more thing I would like to mention here : I think I'm unable to connect using normal  PHP script as well.

Answer (score 2):

In codeignator latest version we need to connect database using Mysqli. So in database file you need to give database driver as mysqli like this,

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Answer (score 1):

New codeignator version have mysqli dbdriver. If we have add mysql instated mysqli then shows following error.

Message: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

**Correct way is** : $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your database username and password matches. Sometimes, these little things matters a lot.

Comment: You're right.. But I'm sure that username and password is correct. I can access MySQL cli using same username & password.

Comment: Hi All, The problem has been resolved:  I reinstalled `php5-common` and `php5-mysql` then restarted the `Apache` webserver.